# Upload a file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have made a input field which allows user to upload a image.

```
       class Form extends Component<{}, IState> {
          constructor(Props) {
            super(Props);
            this.state = {
              image: ""  
            };

         handleImageChange (e) {
          let files = e.target.files;
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
          reader.onload = (e) => {
          console.log(e.target?.result);
          this.setState({image: e.target?.result})
                }
              }

        render() {
         return (
           <input type = "file" onChange = {(e)=> this.handleImageChange(e)} />
      <img id="target" src={this.state.image}
)}
```

I am able to see the uploaded image in my current Form Page. But I want to see the uploaded image in some other page. How will I do that? Do I need to use Props? If yes, how will I implement it. Any help would be appreciated.